# Dart Flutter display Icons

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

Im writing my first code and I want to display a Icon, and I try to use the command `Icon (Icons.star, color: Colors.red, size: 100, ),`. But it doesn't work. Can somebody help me. Thx

Comment: can you show us the code so far?

Comment: All fine I forgot an "," behind the ")" before :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to **`Stackoverflow`**.
Try the following code. Your above code is also correct.

Try to check below line in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Refer [`Flutter Icons`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)

Full Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: Colors.red,
        size: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result screen-> [image]

You can also test the code on [`Dartpad`](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).